# Running Django in Pycharm 17.1

Tags: python, django, pycharm

[image]

I'm trying out the new Pycharm 17.1 Pro edition. I'm trying to run a Django 1.7 project. At the git-bash command line in Win 7, I can run it using:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

I can't figure out how to configure pycharm 1.7 to do this though. The screenshot of my setup is as above.

working config:

[image]

Comment: How about using virtualenv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In field where you have *runserver* write: *http://127.0.0.1:8000/*.
Don' forget to enable Django support in Settings/Language&Frameworks/Django and set settings file, manage script and project root. Also make shure that you choose right Python interpreter(in Django server configuration) - the one which has installed Django. The easiest way to check if you have right interpreter chosen open: Settings/Project:ProjectName/Project Interpreter. It will list all installed packages for chosen interpreter.

Comment: Thanks , I ended up creating a new django server, deleting the old and accepring the provided options. This worked. Screenshot added above: