# Django Server is not running

Tags: python, django, pycharm

[image: Server running]
[image]
The Server is started in pycharm but in browser its showing like above pictures
I am new to Django Framework and I just installed pycharm now.
Can any one please help me out from this??

Comment: On a more serious note, I assume that the base url of your site has an associated route for it? Otherwise that will probably be what's at fault.

Comment: I use Flask on my current project. I believe Django is recommended due to the great amount of resources and docs they have written. Having said that, Flask is also very well documented, there are several amazing tutorials for beginners, and to top it off, Flask allows you to install plugins, which will make life a lot easier. One example would be `flask-wtf` which is a form handler, another could be, `flask-sqlalchemy` and this is really useful and save me huge amounts of time mapping my ORM backend.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/26564/how-to-check-if-a-port-is-blocked-on-a-windows-machine Also, check if your firewall has blocked 8000 port or not.

Comment: Can you see anything happen in the console running the server (where you ran `manage.py runserver`)? If so, go into `mysite/settings.py` and make sure `DEBUG=True`

Comment: Similar your question: [Running Django in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209265/running-django-in-pycharm-17-1?rq=1) Please, check this steps